# How to add custom Angular library package to Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I have a Angular custom library and i want to push the library to Azure DevOps Artifacts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a artifact feed, then build and publish the library to the specific Azure DevOps feed.

Please refer to the following documents to know more about that:

- [Use npm to store JavaScript packages in Azure DevOps Services or
  TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-npm?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows)
- [Publish an npm package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/publish?view=azure-devops)

Besides, there's a blog described about that, it's straightforward to follow : [Create angular library in your private npm registry on AzureDevOps](https://medium.com/digikare/create-angular-library-in-your-private-npm-registry-on-azuredevops-5d6891cb93dd) . Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks ...i'll try this